# Updating Existing Class From UML Diagram in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created a UML diagram and generated a class by using Generate Code feature of Visual Studio Feature Pack 2. I have implemented the methods in that class. When I want add a new method into class from uml diagram and use generate code feature, it remove all implementations in methods but add my newly added method from uml diagram. It acts like removing the existing class and creating it again. How can i update it without removing whole class and just add a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use partial classes.

The classes that are generated should have partial before them, e.g. `public partial class Foo : Bar`; create a new file (file name or location does not matter). The namespace and the class name must be the same as the auto-generated one, and it must include `partial`. The definitions from all the files are combined into a single class, and you don't have to worry about the auto-generated code deleting your extra file.